# Why is 'overflow:auto' CSS not working when using some browsers

Tags: css, browser, posterous

I went to **Settings** > **Edit Theme** > **Advanced** and added this to it, under `<style type="text/css">`, but it doesn't work:

```
pre { overflow: auto; }
code { background-color: LightGrey; padding: 1px 3px; }
```

The first statement doesn't take effect when accessed with Chromium (I expect a horizontal scroll to appear). The second one, which I added for demonstration purposes, works well.

Here's [the page](http://computing.tshepang.net/43853314) you can look at to see how well it doesn't work.

I've tested with these browsers:

- Chromium and Epiphany works not
- Firefox and Konqueror works

### update:

Following [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5123828/5123829#5123829), I've tried all these `whitespace` properties inside the `<pre>` tag: **normal**, **nowrap**, **pre**, **pre-line**, and **pre-wrap**. The problem remains.

Comment: Maybe you've fixed it in the meantime, but on your demo page I get a horz. scrollbar in Chromium 9.

Comment: @mar Yes I have 'fixed'. I have more than one newline in the pre-block, but it's showing as one line :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you float .code left then it will work:

```
.code {float: left;}
pre { white-space: pre;}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a horizontal scroll bar show up, you need to add:

```
pre { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the actual page you have the css:

```
pre { overflow: auto; white-space: pre-line; }
```

This is overwriting any other `white-space` declaration and therefore it will not have horizontal scroll. Changing this to `white-space: nowrap` fixes the problem.

Comment: I did that but there is a problem when there is more than one line: it's as if it's just one line.